# HttpClient request failed when Bearer token is included

Tags: angular, metronic

[image]

When i submit post request to API URL. It fails everytime I include Authorization. When I try to login using API. It works fine. but later on. When I try to get all users using its Auth-token. it fails the request. I am using HttpClient. (@angular/common/http)

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':  'Bearer ' + environment.authTokenKey });
        const users = this.http.post<User[]>(API_USERS_URL, null, { headers: httpHeaders});
        return users;
```

Comment: i am new in angular. sorry i forgot to mention in question.

Comment: What do you mean by fails? Any errors? The request is sent?

Comment: Do you have any `Interceptor` added? Propably you need one and add `withCredentials: true`

Comment: @KamLar i tried using WithCredentials also. But no effect.

Comment: @ Elias Soares 
Just 'Failed'

Comment: `
 intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
 ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const reqHeader = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + authtoken)});
  return next.handle(reqHeader);

`

Comment: You forgot about space between `Bearer` and your `Token`. Add `withCredentials` and it should work, atleast on your screenshot there is no space.

Comment: corrected it later on. But thats not the problem.

Comment: Just fail. I really don't understand what this means.

Comment: Are you getting this header in backend? Can it be decoded? If you added `withCredentials` and backend is receiving the authorization header, there might be problem with decoding it.

Comment: No bro, request is failing without any clue.